# Angular header over https

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http

I use Angular 9 for sending some headers such as page size and current page to my asp.net mvc core back end over IIS server . when my request is to http address every thing is OK ,but when I use https for calling API, header values not sent correctly and pagging not work . 
I test my https back end with postman and it work through it.

```html
 let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
       headers = headers.set('PageSize', pageSize.toString());
       headers = headers.set('CurrentPage', currentPage.toString());
```

How can I send my header request correctly?

Comment: What error can you see? Does the Api call succeed but with incorrect data? If the call fails in https only (but works with postman) it might be because of a CORS issue

Comment: I don't have CORS problem . just my headers not send by https (ssl). my Authorization JWT Token is sending via header but my pagesize not sending. also every thing works with http

Answer (score 1):

Try this way: Make sure you include the headers in your api call

```js
var pageS = pageSize.toString()
var currentP = currentPage.toString()
var headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'PageSize': pageS,
    'CurrentPage': currentP
});

return this._http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/', {
        object
    }, {
        headers
    })
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: I send request and receive response over http correctly . other steps are true and i sned header in my request. my problem is just with https.

Comment: Ah ok. Take a look at this file: https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a